# Using format: 'amd', let/const is not converted to var

Tags: rollup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS2Xi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBzaR.png)
Using format: 'amd', ‘let/const’ is not converted to ‘var’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8hOO.png)
I want it all to be ‘var’

rollup: 2.41.2

Using format: 'amd', ‘let/const’ is not converted to ‘var’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8hOO.png)
I want it all to be ‘var’

rollup: 2.41.2